# How to use timer in drop wizard?

Tags: java, dropwizard, metrics

I need to measure method execution duration statistic.
I decided to use drop wizard.

I rty to follow following article:
https://dzone.com/articles/dropwizard-part-3-measuring-your-application-metri

Looks like this appropriate for my situation:

```
final Timer.Context context = responses.time();//1
        try {
            String userOneName = userOne.get();
            String userTwoName = userTwo.get();
            return new ChatroomView(userOneName, userTwoName, chats.chatBetween(userOneName, userTwoName),
                chats.belongingTo(userOneName)
                    .stream()
                    .map(c -> new ChatView(userOneName, c))
                    .collect(toList()));
        } finally {
            context.stop();//2
        }
```

But In article I could not find what is `responses` object;

Plaese clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();
static final Timer timer = metrics.timer("MyTimer");

static void startReport() {
    ConsoleReporter reporter = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(metrics)
            .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
    reporter.start(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    startReport();
}
```

and then:

```
final Timer.Context context = timer.time();//1
try {
    String userOneName = userOne.get();
    String userTwoName = userTwo.get();
    return new ChatroomView(userOneName, userTwoName, chats.chatBetween(userOneName, userTwoName),
        chats.belongingTo(userOneName)
            .stream()
            .map(c -> new ChatView(userOneName, c))
            .collect(toList()));
} finally {
    context.stop();//2
}
```